# Why does my CrawlerProcess not have the function "crawl"?

Tags: scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from items import BackpageItem, CityvibeItem
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
import re
import time
import sys

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']

    # Set last_age to decide how many pages are crawled
    last_page = 10
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/washington/?page=%s' % page for page in xrange(1,last_page)]

    rules = (

        #Follow all links inside <div class="cat"> and calls parse_item on each link
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths=('//a[@name="listing_link"]')),
            callback='parse_item'),

    )

    # Extract relevent text from the website into a ExampleItem
    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = ExampleItem()

        item['title'] = response.xpath('string(//h2[@class="post-title"]/text())').extract()
        item['desc'] = response.xpath('string(//div[@class="section post-body"]/text())').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['location'] = response.xpath('string(//div[@class="posting"]/div[2]/text())').extract()       
        item['posted_date'] = response.xpath('string(//div[@class="post-date"]/span/text())').extract()#.re("(?<=Posted\s*).*")
        item['crawled_date'] = time.strftime("%c")
        # not sure how to get the other image urls right now
        item['image_urls'] = response.xpath('string(//div[@class="section post-contact-container"]/div/div/img/@src)').extract()
        # I can't find this section on any pages right now
        item['other_ad_urls'] = response.xpath('//a[@name="listing_link"]/@href').extract()
        item['phone_number'] = "".join(response.xpath('//div[@class="post-info"]/span[contains(text(), "Phone")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract())

        item['email'] = "".join(response.xpath('//div[@class="post-info"]/span[contains(text(), "Email")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract())
        item['website'] = "".join(response.xpath('//div[@class="post-info limit"]/span[contains(text(), "Website")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract())
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="post-name"]/text()').extract()

        #uncomment for debugging
        #inspect_response(response, self)
        return item

# process1 = CrawlerProcess({
#     'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
#     #'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1
#     'backpage.pipelines.GeolocationPipeline': 4,
#     'backpage.pipelines.LocationExtractionPipeline': 3,
#     'backpage.pipelines.BackpagePipeline': 5
#     }

# });

    process1 = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })



    process1.crawl(MySpider)
    process1.start()
```

My spider works perfectly when I run it from the command line with

```
scrapy crawl example
```

but I will need to run multiple spiders, so I want to put them all in a script and use CrawlerProcess.  When I try to run this I get the error,

```
AttributeError: 'CrawlerProcess' object has no attribute 'crawl'
```

This is scrapy version 0.24.6.
All items and pipelines are correct, because the spider works from the command line.

Comment: You may want to follow the [docs for 0.24.6](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/practices.html?#run-scrapy-from-a-script), which uses `Crawler` instead of `CrawlerProcess`

Comment: I didn't realize they updated to 1.0 two days ago.  Now I have an openSSL error, which I believe is caused by having an outdated python distribution.

Comment: Updating python 2.7 did not fix the problem.  I get, 
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding
even when I just try to run the tutorial.  No solutions i have found so far have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (was?) a compatibility problem between Scrapy and Scrapyd.  I needed to run Scrapy 0.24 and Scrapyd 1.0.1.
Here is the issue on Github
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/100#issuecomment-115268880