# Proper way to run multiple scrapy spiders

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I just tried running multiple spiders in the same process using [the new scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/practices.html) but I am getting: AttributeError: 'CrawlerProcess' object has no attribute 'crawl'

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988835/why-does-my-crawlerprocess-not-have-the-function-crawl) with the same problem so I tried using the code from the [0.24 documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/practices.html) and got: runspider: error: Unable to load 'price_comparator.py': No module named testspiders.spiders.followall

For 1.0 I imported:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
```

and for 0.24 I imported:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
```

Based on the 0.24 doc, it seems like the code runs one spider through multiple domains, which doesn't seem to be the same as what the 1.0 doc's code does, but I ran both anyway. I do have the code to run both spiders inside of the file where my spiders are defined so that could be a problem. Is there some internal issue with the new version of the code or is there some dependency or code that I'm missing from my program? I have the file with the code from both docs below (I didn't run both versions at the same time).

**Spider Class Definitions**

*relevant code at the bottom*

```
import re
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from concert_comparator.items import ComparatorItem, ComparatorItem2
from twisted.internet import reactor

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
#from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log
#from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from  urlparse import urljoin

bandname = raw_input("Enter a bandname \n")
#location = raw_input("Enter a city \n")
vs_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"
sg_url = "http://www.seatgeek.com/" + bandname + "-tickets"
#sh_url = "http://www.stubhub.com/" + bandname + "-tickets/"
#print sh_url
#rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + item["ticketsLink"]),restrict_xpaths=('.//*/td[3]/a/@href',))callback = "parse_tickets" , follow = True,))
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('tickets')
        price_list = [i.get('p') for i in ticket_info]
        ticketPrice = ''.join(price_list[0])
        loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=" + json_id
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/*/a[@class = "btn btn-primary"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)


class MySpider2(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator2'
    allowed_domains = ["www.seatgeek.com/"]
    start_urls = [sg_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'

    def parse_json2(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        listings_info = jsonresponse.get('listings')
        price_list = [i.get('pf') for i in ticket_info]
        ticketPrice = price_list[0]
        loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price2(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id= ticketsLink.split('/')[6]
        json_url = "https://seatgeek.com/listings?client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4&id=" + json_id + "&_wt=1&&_=1436364489501"
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse2(self, response):
        """

        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/a[@class = "event-listing-title"]/span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/a[@class = "event-listing-venue-link"]/span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , '//a[@class = "event-listing-button"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , '//div[@class = "event-listing-date"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCountry' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressCountry"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , '//div[@class = "event-listing-time"]/text()')

            #ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            tickets_url = "www.seatgeek.com/" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(tickets_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price2, dont_filter = True)
#0.24 code 

# def setup_crawler(domain):
#     spider = FollowAllSpider(domain=domain)
#     settings = get_project_settings()
#     crawler = Crawler(settings)
#     crawler.configure()
#     crawler.crawl(spider)
#     crawler.start()

# for domain in [vs_url, sg_url]:
#     setup_crawler(domain)
# log.start()
# reactor.run()

#1.0 code

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compartible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })
process.crawl(MySpider)        
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start()
```

Comment: Well, I tried your script locally and it works -- I get no exception when running it with Scrapy 1.0.1

Comment: @GHajba What command did you run in the terminal and were you in the root directory of the project when you ran it?

Comment: I copied your code into a simple Python script (so no Scrapy project) and I've had to remove the item `import`s. After that I executed `python twospiders.py`. I suggest you to try it out.

Comment: @GHajba But how can you implement the scrapy crawl spider without scrapy? Did you see it actually crawling the websites and scraping the data in the terminal?

Comment: Scrapy is imported so basically you can start the script like a plain old Python script. The code is at the office so I cannot look right at the result but I guess there were results.

Comment: @GHajba Idk, I just ran the 1.0 code in a new file and I'm still getting the error that 'CrawlerProcess' object has no attribute 'crawl'. I think if you tried the code inside of a scrapy project you would probably get the same error. Do you know of any other way to run multiple scrapy spiders?

Comment: Did you try to upgrade Scrapy to **1.0.1**? Perhaps this is the minor difference.

Comment: @GHajba Yeah I just specifically upgraded scrapy (even though I had already updated the whole system) and I'm not getting the same error with crawlerProcess anymore. Now I'm getting this error: raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Comment: If you can't get this working another solution would be to write a script that calls the command "scrapy list" from your project directory. From their you have a list of every spider name. So you can have this script iterate over the list calling "scrapy crawl {spider name here}". I know this is kind of hackish but it will work if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @rocktheartsm4l Which directory would this file have to be in? The spiders directory or the root of the scrapy project? Also, would I just run that script in the python shell wherever it is? Thanks

Comment: You'd put it in the same folder you usually issue the cmd "scrapy crawl {spider name}" aka your project root

Comment: Sorry on my phone and didn't notice the rest of your question.. You would run it from whatever shell you usually use (bash, powershell, cmd prompt, etc..)