# ImportError: cannot import name CrawlerRunner

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, twisted

I've created a web scraper in scrapy that runs two spiders in the same process, but when I run the code in the terminal using the command: scrapy crawl  then I get: ImportError: cannot import name CrawlerRunner. 
I previously tried other methods for running multiple scrapy spiders simultaneously detailed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303197/proper-way-to-run-mutiple-scrapy-spiders?noredirect=1#comment50638827_31303197) but was unable to solve the issue. I thought that maybe using the twisted library might work but apparently there might be some dependency that I don't have but I can't be sure. Is there something special that needs to be installed in order for the library to be imported? I already have python-twisted installed. The code for the spiders is below:

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from concert_comparator.items import ComparatorItem, ComparatorItem2

bandname = raw_input("Enter a bandname \n")

vs_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"
sg_url = "http://www.seatgeek.com/" + bandname + "-tickets"

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('tickets')
        price_list = [i.get('p') for i in ticket_info]
        ticketPrice = ''.join(price_list[0])
        loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=" + json_id
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/*/a[@class = "btn btn-primary"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)


class MySpider2(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator2'
    allowed_domains = ["www.seatgeek.com/"]
    start_urls = [sg_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'

    def parse_json2(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        listings_info = jsonresponse.get('listings')
        price_list = [i.get('pf') for i in ticket_info]
        ticketPrice = price_list[0]
        loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price2(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id= ticketsLink.split('/')[6]
        json_url = "https://seatgeek.com/listings?client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4&id=" + json_id + "&_wt=1&&_=1436364489501"
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse2(self, response):
        """

        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/a[@class = "event-listing-title"]/span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/a[@class = "event-listing-venue-link"]/span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , '//a[@class = "event-listing-button"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , '//div[@class = "event-listing-date"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCountry' , './/span[@itemprop  = "addressCountry"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , '//div[@class = "event-listing-time"]/text()')

            #ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            tickets_url = "www.seatgeek.com/" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(tickets_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price2, dont_filter = True)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start()
```

Comment: do you have scrapy installed? http://scrapy.org/
what does `import scarpy` say?

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer Yes, I have scrapy installed. I don't get an error when I import scrapy.

Comment: Is this file called `scrapy.py` by any chance?

Comment: @Glyph I'm not getting the same error with crawlerProcess anymore after having updated scrapy again. Now I'm getting this error: raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable. I have been using the command: <scrapy crawl comparator> in the terminal so I'm not sure if thats causing a problem because that is technically the command for running one spider in specific.

Comment: Are you supposed to be calling `reactor.run()` in a crawler script?  I would assume that the `scrapy` command-line tool would do that for you.

Comment: @Glyph I changed back to using crawlerProcess before I ran it last. The new code is posted. Do you know what command I should be using in the terminal to run both spiders btw?

Comment: No clue, unfortunately. I am an expert in Twisted but I have never used Scrapy.